# Connect to MS Access database from classic ASP

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I am trying to connect a MS Access database from classic ASP script.

I am using 64bit Windows 7 OS running IIS7

I have following piece of code:

```
Dim Connection
Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Response.Write("object created...")
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("D://Somnath//ExtraLogistics//Source//ZipDB.mdb") & ";" 
Response.Write("connected...")
```

but I am getting this error `The website cannot display the page` in browser while running application on IIS.

Please help me to connect to the Access database from my IIS.

Comment: Did you check the server logs?

Comment: Does your access path have permissions to be be accessed by your IIS services?

Comment: if you remove the connections does the response.writes work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MapPath does not look correct.

Have a look at this [ASP reference](http://access.databases.aspfaq.com/why-does-access-give-me-unspecified-error-messages.html).

**EDIT:**

Server.MapPath points to the Physical location of a virtual reference:

For Example:
'Physical path of the root directory
Response.Write Server.MapPath("/")

'Physical path of DataDirectory
Response.Write Server.MapPath("/DataDirectory/")

Place the **ZipDB.mdb** in the root of your website and change the **Server.MapPath("/")**

Comment: i have created virtual directory in ISS for the source folder and the database file i.e.ZipDB.mdb is also placed in same folder but still it doesn't working...

Answer (score 1):

Use a "file dsn":

```
conn.open "driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};dbq=c:\filepath\yourdb.mdb;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Server.MapPath converts a URL path to the physical path on the server so Server.MapPath("D://Somnath//ExtraLogistics//Source//ZipDB.mdb") is almost certainly wrong.

If the mdb file is located at http://yourhost/Somnath/ExtraLogistics/Source/ZibDB.mdb then you would use `Server.MapPath("/Somnath/ExtraLogistics/Source/ZibDB.mdb")` and Server.MapPath would give you the location of the mdb file in the server's filesystem.

If the file is located at D:\Somnath\ExtraLogistics\Source\ZipDB.mdb then just use that filepath and remove Server.MapPath completely.

Like so:
`conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\Somnath\ExtraLogistics\Source\ZipDB.mdb;"`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you want to store your database in a parent directory relative to the location where you execute the asp files. If you don't the database is available through a url in the browser.

Also note that to make this work, 'Allow Parent Paths' must be enabled in IIS.