# The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file on Network Location

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I am developing an ASP classic website that connects to a MS Access database and display data at real time (I know MS Access is not the best option for this purpose, but my company uses it for everything, so I just decide to use it for now). When the MS database is on my hard disk drive (C:), it works fine. But when I move the database to one of the network locations, such as U:\tracking, it gives me this error:

```
Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005'
The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file 'U:\tracking\database.mdb'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.
```

I know it is probably due to the security permission (read and write) about creating temporary files (.ldb) for MS Access database. I reset the security permission on the U:\tracking folder, which contains the database, but it did not work. I even gave full control to every account listed in the "Group and user names" session, but the error was still there.

I also checked my Authentication setting in my IIS manager. The only enabled setting is Anonymous Authentication, and I use Application pool identity at this point. If I use specific user, I may add it to the above permission list and give it the appropriate permission, but I cannot guarantee it is appropriate. Any ideas about what I should do to connect to the database on the network location? Any help would be appreciated!

Following is the simple code I use to connect to the database:

```
Dim dbCon
Set dbCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbCon.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
dbCon.Open = "U:\tracking\database.mdb"
```

Comment: You need to grant access both to the share and to the folder itself.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "granting access to the share"? I am able to read/write/modify files in network locations such as U:/.

Comment: Talk to your network admin. Shares have one set of permissions, drives/folders another set. And the permissions in question are not yours but those assigned to the application.

Comment: To access network resources the Application Pool Identity will need to be set to the Network Service account *(but this is not recommended)*.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using the ASO connection string parameter as this [W3Schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_conn_connectionstring.asp) indicates.

```
<%
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.open server.mappath("database.mdb")

conn.close
%>
```

Also, path names do not need to be explicitly defined if [server map targets the root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656685/connect-to-ms-access-database-from-classic-asp). This is especially true since backslashes prove problematic for web URLs that use forward slashes.

Comment: Thank you but using the ASO connection string parameter did not change anything. I think the problem is about network location permission rather than the code about connection. Server.mappath may not apply in my case, because I cannot put my database in the root directory of my website (due to specific requirements).

Comment: I think you may mean ADO *(ActiveX Data Objects)*. The version used by Classic ASP is called `ADODB` *(Namespace used by all ADO components)*.

Comment: @GloomyMountain Couple of things, don't use MS Access on a publicly accessible website use SQL Express / MySQL or similar, MS Access was never designed to be consumed in a web environment. Also `Server.MapPath()` is a bad idea as it requires the database to be accessible from the website, ideally the database file should always be stored outside the web application space with the appropriate permission for the web application to access it. But from your original question you already seem aware of this.